# Send JSON data from client to server via javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I am trying to send a simple stringified JSON object from client.html to be received by server.js using http.
The server is implemented using Node.js
The issue is that it just doesn't send from the client to the server (as I am expecting it's a POST method that should work). While client receives the response from the server and shows it on the console.

Client.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Client </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
   xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
   xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify({x: 5}));
}


httpGetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:3000", function(response) {
  console.log("recieved ... ", response);
});
</script>
</body>
```

server.js

```
// content of index.js
const http = require('http')
const port = 3000

const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.url)
  response.end('Hello Node.js Server!') // this is read on the client side
  request.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("recieved: " + JSON.parse(data).x) // Not showing on the console !!!!
  })
}

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler)

server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }

  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

to run server.js, type in the command terminal:

```
node server.js
```

Side Note:
I know this question is most probably very trivial, but I have mostly worked with c++, python and I have never worked in web development stuff except later. 
Please help me get this into something

Comment: You can use express.js framework.

Comment: Could it be that `request.on('data'...` never triggers because you aren't POSTing or PUTting the form?

Comment: send(argument)"[If the request method is GET or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)"

Comment: yeah @James , I did console.log in this code section before I post this question and I found that this callback is actually never triggered

Comment: @ProfessorAllman .. so that means I need to something like: xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl) before I send

Comment: Yes, either change your node server to listen to GET or make your javascript do a POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to ProfessorAllman
just replacing "GET" with "POST" gets what I needed 
client.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <title>Client </title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
{
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
      callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
   xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous
   xmlHttp.send(JSON.stringify({x: 5}));
}


httpGetAsync("http://127.0.0.1:3000", function(response) {
  console.log("recieved ... ", response);
});
</script>
</body>
```